# Add +1 number to an array

Tags: php

```
session_start();

echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='random' placeholder='Product' >";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

if(!$_SESSION['list']) {
    $_SESSION['list'] = array(); // create session
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['random'])) { // Check if input is empty
    echo "* Input is empty!";
} elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['random'])) {
    $_SESSION['list'][] += 1; // add +1 to array
}

foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br>"; // shows the list/array
}
```

So I tried to make array that add +1 number on a submit, but my array keeps being 1, so it doesn't go like: 1,2,3,4,5... but it goes like: 1,1,1,1,1,1 . They don't add up. How do I fix this?

Comment: make a variable for it, at the moment it is making a new array member, then adding 1 to it (defaults to 0)

Comment: how about you use array keys instead? I don't see the point of adding numbers to an array like that unless if you have a different set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array `$arr`, or `$_SESSION['list']` in your case, it is possible to [append an element](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) to the end of the array as follows.

```
$arr[] = 'new element';
```

You try to combine this with the [`+=` operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). This will first append `0` to the array and then increment it, resulting in `1` being appended all the time.

It looks like what you actually want to do is this:

```
$arr[] = end($arr) + 1;
```

That is, take the [last](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) value of the array, add `1` to it and append that to the array.

Comment: It add 1 to it, but it doesn't go any further? So it goes from 0 to 1, but it stays at 1.

Comment: Never mind I got it. it was = $_SESSION['lijst'][] = end($_SESSION['lijst']) + 1; I forgot the [] at the end. Thanks for the help :D